# t.test with multiple group variables and multiple scale variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataset `mydat`(part of):

```
structure(list(city = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("New-York", "Washington"), class = "factor"), 
    x1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), x2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), x3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), x4 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L), x5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L
    ), x6 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), x7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), var1 = c(10L, 71L, 49L, 
    70L, 79L, 46L, 87L, 57L, 81L, 68L), var2 = c(34L, 17L, 28L, 
    63L, 95L, 99L, 40L, 63L, 24L, 90L), var3 = c(21L, 89L, 81L, 
    26L, 59L, 87L, 84L, 24L, 27L, 83L), var4 = c(86L, 70L, 45L, 
    40L, 95L, 94L, 39L, 97L, 89L, 30L)), .Names = c("city", "x1", 
"x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

This dataset has 7 group binary variables(in real data there are more group and scale variables).
I have to compare them by 4 scale variables.
I do not want to сompare by one variable like that

```
t.test(var1~x1,data=mydat)
t.test(var2~x1,data=mydat)
t.test(var3~x1,data=mydat)
t.test(var4~x1,data=mydat)

t.test(var1~x2,data=mydat)
t.test(var2~x2,data=mydat)
t.test(var3~x2,data=mydat)
t.test(var4~x2,data=mydat)
```

How to write a loop so that all the grouping variables are alternately compared in var1, then all the grouping variables are compared in var2 and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can generate the required combinations of required variables using `expand.grid`.

```
combinations = expand.grid(colnames(mydat)[9:12],colnames(mydat)[2:8],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then use `mapply` to the corresponding pairs of variables and apply the `t.test()`.

```
mapply(function(x,y){t.test(formula=as.formula(paste0(x,"~",y)),data=mydat)},combinations$Var1,combinations$Var2,SIMPLIFY = FALSE,USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Output will be a list of 28 comparisons:

```
[[1]]

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  var1 by x1
t = -0.30246, df = 7.6648, p-value = 0.7703
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-35.45353  27.28686
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
   60.16667        64.25000 


[[2]]

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  var2 by x1
t = 0.98709, df = 7.9696, p-value = 0.3526
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
-24.07911  60.07911
sample estimates:
mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
       62.5            44.5
```

**EDIT** (As requested in comments):

```
library(plyr)

combinations = expand.grid(colnames(mydat)[9:12],colnames(mydat)[2:8],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

myfun<-function(dat){mapply(function(x,y){t.test(formula=as.formula(paste0(x,"~",y)),data=dat)},combinations$Var1,combinations$Var2,SIMPLIFY = FALSE,USE.NAMES = FALSE)

dlply(.data = mydat,.variables = "city",.fun = "myfun")
```

Comment: Thanks for the accurate and prompt answer!Tell me,  how to divide the same analysis into cities. i.e. perform it separately for Washington and New york(city var)? You can make this edition in your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution:

```
xvars <- grep('x[0-9]{1}', names(mydat), value = TRUE)
testvars <- grep('var[0-9]{1}', names(mydat), value = TRUE)

lapply(xvars, function(x) lapply(testvars, function(y) t.test(mydat[,y] ~ mydat[,x], data = mydat) ))
```

which gives (output truncated due to size):

> ```
> [[1]]
> [[1]][[1]]
>
>   Welch Two Sample t-test
>
> data:  mydat[, y] by mydat[, x]
> t = -0.30246, df = 7.6648, p-value = 0.7703
> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  -35.45353  27.28686
> sample estimates:
> mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
>        60.16667        64.25000 
>
>
> [[1]][[2]]
>
>   Welch Two Sample t-test
>
> data:  mydat[, y] by mydat[, x]
> t = 0.98709, df = 7.9696, p-value = 0.3526
> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  -24.07911  60.07911
> sample estimates:
> mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
>            62.5            44.5
> ```